# SceneKit: Create SCNNodes from models at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am making a SceneKit game, and I have a folder with my models (file.obj, file.mtl, file.png). I can drag the models to the game.scn file.

```
let node = rootNode.childNode(withName: "boxTarget", recursively: true)!.flattenedClone()
node.isHidden = false
```

Then I look for the name of the node and I create a flattenedClone.

But I think that there will be a better way to create multiple SCNNodes with models, dynamically, at runtime, without adding them to the game.scn file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I did mine something like this:

```
func initGameNodes() {
        scene = SCNScene()

        gameNodes = SCNNode()
        gameNodes.name = "gameNodes"
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(gameNodes)

        initLights()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(camera.cameraEye)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(camera.cameraFocus)

        camera.reset()
}

func loadCollada(sceneName: String, objName: String) -> SCNNode {
        let vScene = SCNScene(named: sceneName)!
        let gObject = vScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: objName, recursively: true)!
        return gObject
}

func createProjectileNodes(vMissile: weaponTypes) -> SCNNode {
            switch vMissile
            {
            case .defenseMissile:
                let vNode = loadCollada(sceneName: "art.scnassets/Models/missile.dae", objName: "Default")
                vNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
                vNode.name = "Missile01"
                return vNode
            case . etc.
            }
}
```

Comment: I think that the problem with that approach is that you access to a file, and that takes time, so the frame rate goes down. What I am trying to do is to load more nodes of one class, for example, without time penalties. Maybe I have to recycle nodes, or create many nodes when the scene load.